# Create a windows service in a salt state

Tags: salt-stack

I know how to create a windows service by doing,

```
salt service.create "servicename" "c:\executable.exe" display="serviceIcreated"
```

How can I incorportate this into a state?

```
c:\temp\somedir:
  file.recurse:
    -source: salt:/d/ser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `service.create` is not available in **Salt States** you will need to run the **execution module** from within your own state or sls file.

You could do it this way:

```
create_executable:
  module.run:
    - name: service.create
    - m_name: servicename
    - bin_path: c:\executable.exe
    - display: serviceIcreated
```

About the piece of code in your question I did not understand how it adds value to your question.

> ```
> c:\temp\somedir:   
>    file.recurse:
>     -source: salt:/d/ser
> ```

If it is relevant, please make an edit in order to make it easier to understand.

Comment: thanks. i put that extra code as an example. dummy code.